'updating the entity providers failed'. microsoft sentinal
I am having some issues while enabling the UEBA feature in a Sentinel instance. When I try to turn the switch ON, I get the following error message:

Updating the Entity Providers failed.

I am trying this with a global admin account but still getting the error.


Could you edit your question and add more details on your requirement?

Hi @HainJoseph Any update?

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to enable the UEBA feature in a Sentinel instance with only Global Admin role:

To resolve the error, make sure to assign Microsoft Sentinel Contributor role to signed-in user under your workspace like this:

When I tried again after assigning above role, Entity providers info updated successfully as below:

Along with Global admin role, signed-in user must have Microsoft Sentinel Contributor role under log analytics workspace to resolve the error.
Reference:
Enable entity behavior analytics to detect advanced threats | Microsoft Learn
